# How python multi-threading/queue works for script to download and install image to all devices

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, subprocess, python-multithreading

I'm new to python, multithreading, queue, and locking. What I'm trying to achieve is to login to many devices all at once, check for new image, download an image, then install it on all devices, in multi-threading process, download has to be done before start installing. I tried the following concept but I have no clue how to accomplish or connect/glue them together, any help will be appreciated in advance!

```
  from threading import Thread
  import Queue
  import re
  from LoginCli import Device_Under_test
  import sys, os, string, threading
  import time

  # some global vars
  num_threads = 25
  ips_q = Queue.Queue()
  out_q = Queue.Queue()
  outlock = threading.Lock()

  # build IP array
  ips = []
  for i in range(100,200):
    ips.append("10.10.10."+str(i))

  user = 'root'
  pword = 'password'  
  log = 'output.log'

  def login_to_device (i, q):
   """get hosts in queue"""
      while True:
        # get an IP item form queue
        ip = q.get()

        cmd = "check for image"

        #login to device:this works just fine using my loginCli script
        LoginCli = Device_Under_test(str(ip), user, pword)
        print_cmd= LoginCli.send_exp(cmd)

      with outlock:
         print print_cmd

      q.task_done()

   def image_download (i, q):
     while True:
        #get an IP item form queue
        ip = q.get()
        cmd = "download for image"

        #NOT sure if I need to login again!
        LoginCli = Device_Under_test(str(ip), user, pword)
        print_cmd= LoginCli.send_exp(cmd)
        search = re.search(r'image download completed 100%', LoginCli)

        #if is done 100% completed then start installing the image 
        #Once installing is completed then reboot all devices 
      with outlock:
         print print_cmd      
      q.task_done()


    # Not sure if I need these functions?
    def image_downoad (i, q):

    def image_install (i, q):

     # start the thread pool
    for i in range(num_threads):
      worker = Thread(target=login_to_device, args=(i, ips_q))
      worker.setDaemon(True)
      worker.start()

    for i in range(num_threads):
      worker = Thread(target=image_downoad, args=(i, ips_q))
      worker.setDaemon(True)
      worker.start()

     # fill queue
    for ip in ips:
      ips_q.put(ip)

     # wait until worker threads are done to exit    
    ips_q.join()

    # print result
    while True:
      try:
        msg = out_q.get_nowait()
      except Queue.Empty:
        break
    print msg
```

Comment: Is the aim to sync all images across devices?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, say there are 20 Cisco devices and need to instal say image 5.0.2 on all devices on the network..Thanks